# vb crystal report error when run on client pc

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I develop a simple crystal report programs with VB using VS 2012 in a win 8.1 Pro 64 bit. There are two major parts in the program, data grid and crystal report view. the first time the program is executed, it will appear DataGrid that will display data from the input file of MS. Access. then the program will display a crystal report contains data from the DataGrid .

I've created the executable program (setup.exe) using Installshield Limited Edition Project. I've set its compatibility to run on all platforms. I tried to install on my pc and I try to run the program, the result is a program can run well. I tried to install on the client PC, the installation process went well, but when I try to run the application an error occured. "An unhandled exception has occured in your application .... etc.".

I've installed crystal report viewer and .net framework 4.5 (same as my framework on my pc) on the client pc, but still the same error. client pc using windows 7 32 bit. It's been almost a week I try to find the cause of the error and look for solutions and tried a variety of ways to solve this problem, but I still have not managed to find it. I am still new to crystal report and I am very frustrated because of this problem. I would appreciate any solution so that this problem can be solved. Thank You.

Comment: Please provide the whole error message. Saying "An unhandled exception has occured in your application" doesn't help in finding out the error.

Comment: However, I finally found the solution. to make crystal report works at the client machine, it must be installed crystal report runtime engine for .NET Framework first. Then I install crystal report runtime engine for .NET Framework and the program eventually went well. No matter the platform differences, as long as .Net framework version 4.5 can be installed and crystal report runtime engine for .NET Framework already installed.

Comment: The problem occurred because I have not installed the components needed to run the crystal report.
Initially I guess after installing the crystal report viewer I've given crystal report about the components it needs. but actually what its need is a crystal report runtime engine for .NET Framework.
Hopefully, this solution can be a reference for you when experiencing the same problem.